# im trying two different questions in my project one is easy but the code isnt working as should. also the second question involves matching key words

Tags: python

Hi I'm Matthew and I've been trying to code for two weeks and I'm having an issue with my questions. So for the first question I want to ask the user a question followed with two more attempts if they get it wrong, but I want it in a certain way for example "there are 100 bricks in a plane one falls out how many are left?" not a trick question 99 but if the user did get it wrong after answering I want try again printed after and if they mess it up again "try again" then if they mess up a third time I want a message to be shown that you failed. but I also want if you do get it correct a message will state that you got it right.

```
bricks: str = "99"
guess = ""
guesscount = 0
guesslimit = 2
outofguesses = False
quest1 = ("how many are left?: ")

if input(quest1) != bricks:
    while guess != bricks and not (outofguesses):
        if guesscount < guesslimit:
           guess = input("try again! ")
           guesscount += 1
        else:
            outofguesses = True
            print("BAKA!")
            print("the correct answer is 99")
            print("next question")
if input(quest1) == bricks:
    print("congrats you know how to do math")
    print("next question")
```

The second question I haven't really put much effort into cause I've been trying to figure out the first one but I need to ask the user "how do you put a elephant in a refrigerator in three easy steps?" the answer is open the door put the elephant in close the door. the way I was thinking about going about this is using key words, my key word list would be ["open, put, place, close, shut, door, elephant"] so if they got certain amount or certain words correct, they would pass maybe my way is a bit complicated and if you have an easier way to go about it I'm open ears.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: how do I edit my post?

Comment: With the [edit] button under your question...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try doing it in while loop.

```
bricks: str = "99"
guesscount = 0
guesslimit = 2
outofguesses = False
quest1 = ("how many are left?: ")

while input(quest1) != bricks:
    guesscount += 1
    if guesscount > guesslimit:
        outofguesses = True
    else:
        print("Try again!")
        break
if outofguesses:
    print("BAKA!")
    print("the correct answer is 99")
    print("next question")
else:
    print("congrats you know how to do math")
    print("next question")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).